# Dynamically change the HTML <img> src attribute using Java Script or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to change the html img src value dynamically from the value from hidden text field using Jquery or Java script.

```
<p><img id="yui_img" height="333" width="345"></p>

function onImgChange()
 {
document.getElementById('yui_img').src=document.getElementById('addProductLinksCreateForm:addProductLinkUrlValue').value;

 }
```

I got the value in the DOM but it is not getting reflected in it. Old image is maintained.

Comment: 1. are you using jquery or pure javascript and 2. please post some more of the html of what you are trying to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, but you need to ensure that these are the case:

- Does the textbox tag look like `<input type="text" id="addProductLinksCreateForm:addProductLinkUrlValue">`?
- Are you calling `onImgChange()` at all? You could try `document.getElementById('addProductLinksCreateForm:addProductLinkUrlValue').onchange = onImgChange;` to allow that to happen when the user switches to a different text box.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, it would look like:

```
function onImgChange() {
     $('#yui_img').attr('src', function(i, src) {
         return $('#addProductLinksCreateForm').attr('src');
     });
}
```